# Why I forward DLL function using .DEF file failed in VS2022?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

## Background

I want to develop a **proxy** DLL referred to this article: [DLL Hijacking using DLL Proxying technique](https://lucabarile.github.io/Blog/dll_hijacking_and_proxying/index.html).

So the **proxy** DLL should export functions with the same **name** and **ordinal** as the **target** DLL.

For those functions that are not hijacked, just forward it to **target** DLL.

There are two ways to do it:

1. Add a [comment pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=msvc-170) into source

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:func=target_module.func,@100")
```

2. Create a .def([module-definition file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=msvc-170)) file, and forward it in [EXPORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-170) section:

```
EXPORTS
  func = target_module.func @100
```

## Environment

OS: Windows10 19044.2604

Platform: x64

IDE: Visual Studio 2022

## What I did

I tried both two methods, the first works well. But the second report a link error.

### the first method

1. Open visual studio 2022 and create an empty DLL project.
2. Add the comment pragma above.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "/export:func=target_module.func,@100,NONAME")

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Project built successfully.

Let's check it by dumpbin, `dumpbin /EXPORTS .\example.dll`:

```
...
    ordinal hint RVA      name

        100    0          func (forwarded to target_module.func)
...
```

The exported 'func' is forwarded to 'target_module.func' as expected.

### the second method

1. Comment out the pragma line.
2. Create a `dll.def` file

```
EXPORTS
    func = target_module.func @100
```

3. Set the project properties, Linker->Input->Module Definition File: `dll.def`
4. When I build the project again, the linker report error: **LNK2001, unresolved external symbol func.**

What's the problem?

The linker shouldn't figure out the 'func' symbol.
It's expected just forward 'func' to target_module's 'func' entry.

Comment: Can you tell us what architecture you're targeting (x86, x64, Arm) and show us the declaration of your exported function (including any `__stdcall` or similar attributes). These can be important.

Comment: The linker appears to double-check that target_module.dll actually exports func.  Try changing it to, say, `func = user32.SetWindowPos` and now it is happy.  If it can't find the .dll or the export then it complains.  The exact rules it uses to locate the .dll are not documented anywhere, I couldn't find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I tested two different usages.

Considering A.dll load B.dll.

Case 1:

```
EXPORTS
   fun3=B.func
```

You need to add dependencies in Project A->Properties->Linker->Input.

See: [To add the DLL import library to your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-import-library-to-your-project)

Case 2:

```
   EXPORTS
       fun3=B.#42
```

Add   dependencies and   additional snippet in A:

```
typedef void (*fun)(void);// E.g. void fun(void)
fun fun3;//fun @42 in B.def
```

Comment: Hi, @司雨寒 I updated my answer. Please check it.